# Unable to add data to firebase from angular and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm just trying to add a list of names to a Firebase using angularFire. My scripts are simple:

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://list-detail-001.firebaseio.com/");
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  // synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
  // click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!

    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "users");

    $scope.newUser={};

    $scope.add=function(){
        console.log($scope.newUser);
        console.log($scope.users);
        console.log(syncObject);
        $scope.users.$add($scope.newUser);
        $scope.newUser='';
    }
})
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h2 class="title">Blank Starter</h2>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item item-input-inset" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="newUser.title">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-small" ng-click="add()">
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

My app.js is standard for ionic except I injected the firebase module:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers','firebase'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

I just want to be able to add one name at a time from my index.html to firebase. The firebase is currently empty. I want to use this app to be able to add in some dummy data. I just cannot seem to get it to work. $scope.users.$add or even $scope.users.push seems to be an undefined function. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays) you should be using `$firebaseArray` in your case $firebaseObject.

Is it possible that you're missing Firebase concept? Firebase object is not a collection. If you want to store data you do it on key/value basis. Arrays in Firebase is a sweetener for `{0: val1, 1: val2 ....}`. Read Firebase warnings about arrays before using them

Comment: I see. Yes, the array I plan on adding is simple: It'll probably look like this: $scope.users=[{"id":"1", "title":"John Doe"},...] I'm hoping I just have to add the "John Doe" while firebase auto-adds the "id". Is that possible, and if so, what modifications would my code need? Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have resolved the issue using your $firebaseArray documentation! I cannot seem to be able to upvote your answer as I don't have enough points. But thank you, 
Kirill Slatin

Comment: @user3068930, Now you can ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with this:

controller.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://list-detail-001.firebaseio.com/users");
    $scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);

  $scope.add=function(){
    $scope.users.$add({
      text: $scope.newUser
    });
  }
});
```

only change I made to index.html was this line:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="newUser">
```